# Databricks - Creating output file

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I'm pretty new to databricks, so excuse my ignorance.
I have a databricks notebook that creates a table to hold data. I'm trying to output the data to a pipe delimited file using another notebook which is using python. If I use the 'Order By' clause each record is created in a seperate file. If I leave the clause out of the code I get 1 file, but it's not in order

The code from the notebook is as follows

```
%python

try:

  dfsql = spark.sql("select field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, field_6, field_7, field_8, field_9, field_10, field_11, field_12,  field_13, field_14, field_15, field_16 from dbsmets1mig02_technical_build.tbl_tech_output_bsmart_update ORDER BY MSN,Sort_Order") #Replace with your SQL

except:

  print("Exception occurred")

if dfsql.count() == 0:

  print("No data rows")

else:

  dfsql.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").option("delimiter", "|").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/publisheddatasmets1mig/smetsmig1/mmt/bsmart")
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark creates a file per partition when writing files. So your order by is creating lots of partitions. Generally you want multiple files as that means you get more throughput - if you have 1 file/partition then you are only using one thread - therefore only 1 CPU on your workers is active - the others are idle which makes it a very expensive way of solving your problem.

You could leave the order by in and coalesce back into a single partition:

```
dfsql.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").option("delimiter", "|").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/publisheddatasmets1mig/smetsmig1/mmt/bsmart")
```

Even if you have multiple files you can point your other notebook at the folder and it will read all files in the folder.

Comment: Simon, now creating a single output file, which is exactly what I need, Many Thanks

Comment: Ah, was too quick to respond. I'm getting 1 file, but no line feeds at the end of each record. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I have done something similar to what simon_dmorias suggested. I am not sure if there is a better way to do so, as this doesn't scale very well but if you are working with a small dataset it will work.

simon_dmorias suggested: `df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").option("delimiter", "|").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/mountone/data/")`

This will write a single partition in a directory `/mnt/mountone/data/data-<guid>-.csv`, which I believe is not what you are looking for, right? You just want `/mnt/mountone/data.csv`, similar to the pandas `.to_csv` function.

Therefore, I will write it to a temporary location on the cluster (not on the mount).

`df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").option("delimiter", "|").mode("overwrite").save("/tmpdir/data")`

I will then use the `dbutils.fs.ls("/tmpdir/data")` command to list the directory contents and identify the name of the csv file that was written in the directory i.e. `/tmpdir/data/data-<guid>-.csv`.

Once you have the CSV file name, I will use the `dbutils.fs.cp` function to copy the file to a mount location and rename the file. This allows you to have a single file without the directory, which is what I believe you were looking for.

`dbutils.fs.cp("/tmpdir/data/data-<guid>-.csv", "/mnt/mountone/data.csv")`